# Finding k largest elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

Why the following approach isn't working for large inputs?

```
def finder(arr,n,k):
    l2 = []
    arr.sort()
    for x in range(n-1,k,-1):
        l2.append(arr[x])
    return l2
```

PS: It works when I write

arr.sort(reverse = True)

Comment: Can you give an input where it fails and describe expected and actual behavior?

Comment: That doesn't work for **any** input.

Comment: @Manuel it is working for this input -> N = 5, K = 2
Arr[] = {12, 5, 787, 1, 23}

Comment: See for yourself   
 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZSbCDEPDPmmo6ASNK4rs-TwVGYjFKjC6

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon 42 is the size of array and 30 is value of k. Then the next numbers are the elments of array.

Comment: It's not about my time. And I don't need to look at the code, as I know 100% that you're not telling the truth. That code crashes with an error (unless you give it an `arr` object whose `sort` method has an infinite loop or so, so it never gets to the `NameError` for `n`).

Comment: Also, you'd better say what `N` is supposed to be. It's not in the text, it doesn't make sense for the task, you're not using it, and it can't be the length of `arr` because that can be gotten with `len(arr)` so nobody would make that an extra parameter.

Comment: My bad. N and n mean the same. Also, lie is a strong word. You might want to use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code has an error: `n` instead of `N` in `range(n-1,k,-1)`.  Also, you are returning the N-k largest values, instead of the k largest.  Python knows the lengths of its lists so providing the `N` parameter is only going to allow for mistakes (i.e. N not equal to list size).  Also, it is generally a bad practice to modify the parameters you are given so you should not use `.sort()` on `arr`.  Using `.sort()` also limits the type of parameters you can pass to your function (e.g. it would not work on an iterator)

The whole function could be reduced to:

```
def finder(arr,k): return sorted(arr)[-k:]
```

But this requires sorting the whole array.  You can get the result more efficiently using heapq:

```
from heapq import nlargest

def finder(arr,k): return nlargest(k,arr)
```

Comment: Right. N and n mean the same it was a typo.